# how to set string specific hostname in C?

Tags: c

So, I am trying to learn socket programming in C (and I am a noob in C), but how do we set string based hostname. For example:

```
  memset(&echoServAddr, 0, sizeof(echoServAddr));     /* Zero out structure */
    echoServAddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;             /* Internet address family */
    echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);   /* Server IP address */
    //echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = servIP;
    echoServAddr.sin_port        = htons(echoServPort); /* Server port */
```

Over here:

```
 echoServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);
```

servIP must be of form 127.0.0.1 but I want to use strings like localhost?

Comment: you can just get the ip of a hostname with `getaddrinfo` :http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `getaddrinfo` function. It's used like:

```
getaddrinfo(machine, port, &addrinfo, &addrinfo_result)
```

As example:

```
struct addrinfo hints; //This "helps" to search
struct addrinfo *result;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;  
hints.ai_socktype =  SOCK_DGRAM; //Your socket's type
/* There are some more like protocol, flags.. */

error = getaddrinfo(argv[1], argv[2], &hints, &result);
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `getaddrinfo`, you will want to look into `gethostbyname` and `gethostbyaddr`.

`gethostbyname`, particularly, does what you are looking to do.  It asks the resolver library to take a string and perform a forward lookup to resolve it to a number:

```
#include <netdb.h>
extern int h_errno;

struct hostent *gethostbyname(const char *name);
```

Comment: `gethostbyname()` and `gethostbyaddr()` are not POSIX anymore. POSIX recommends to use `getaddrinfo()` and `getnameinfo()` instead.